# Ошибка mysql.connector.pooling при получении соединения внутри multiprocessing.pool

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pool

Передо мной стоит задача: У меня есть массив значений(для примера взял маленькую выборку),каждый элемент которого необходимо передать в функцию DB. Внутри функции необходимо занести это значение в Базу Данных MySQL(опять же,для примера всего один запрос,на деле - намного больше). Мне необходимо заносить данные в Базу Данных параллельно,это важное условие моего проекта, для этого я использую библиотеку python3 multiprocessing и класс Pool.
Что бы увеличить скорость занесения данных в БД , я использую возможности библиотеки mysql.connector , а точнее создаю пул процессов с помощью pooling,который будет держать открытым 15 соединений с MySQL и переиспользовать их. Как следствие, пропадет необходимость создавать новые соединения каждый раз в функции DB и увеличится скорость.

Ниже приведен упрощенный код, с помощью которого можно повторить ошибку.

```
import multiprocessing
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector.connection import MySQLConnection
from mysql.connector import pooling

connection_pool = mysql.connector.pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(pool_name="maria_pool",pool_size = 15, pool_reset_session = True, host = "10.250.7.19",database = "database",user = "database",password = "password")

def DB(i):

    Variable = i

    connection_object = connection_pool.get_connection()
    if connection_object.is_connected():
       db_Info = connection_object.get_server_info()
       print(db_Info)
    cursor = connection_object.cursor()

    sql = "INSERT INTO table_z (Variable,Variable_2) VALUES (%s,%s)"
    cursor.execute(sql,(Variable,Variable))
    connection_object.commit()

    print(type(cursor))

    cursor.close()
    connection_object.close()
    return None

massiv = ["one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","sixteen","seventeen","eightteen","nineteen","twenty","twenty one","twenty two","twenty three"]

obj2 = multiprocessing.Pool(15)
obj2.map(DB,massiv)
```

---

Вывод данной программы таков:

```
5.5.5-10.3.13-MariaDB-1:10.3.13+maria~bionic-log
5.5.5-10.3.13-MariaDB-1:10.3.13+maria~bionic-log
5.5.5-10.3.13-MariaDB-1:10.3.13+maria~bionic-log
5.5.5-10.3.13-MariaDB-1:10.3.13+maria~bionic-log
5.5.5-10.3.13-MariaDB-1:10.3.13+maria~bionic-log
5.5.5-10.3.13-MariaDB-1:10.3.13+maria~bionic-log
5.5.5-10.3.13-MariaDB-1:10.3.13+maria~bionic-log
5.5.5-10.3.13-MariaDB-1:10.3.13+maria~bionic-log
5.5.5-10.3.13-MariaDB-1:10.3.13+maria~bionic-log
5.5.5-10.3.13-MariaDB-1:10.3.13+maria~bionic-log
5.5.5-10.3.13-MariaDB-1:10.3.13+maria~bionic-log
5.5.5-10.3.13-MariaDB-1:10.3.13+maria~bionic-log
5.5.5-10.3.13-MariaDB-1:10.3.13+maria~bionic-log
5.5.5-10.3.13-MariaDB-1:10.3.13+maria~bionic-log
5.5.5-10.3.13-MariaDB-1:10.3.13+maria~bionic-log
<class 'mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor'>
<class 'mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor'>
<class 'mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor'>
<class 'mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor'>
<class 'mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor'>
<class 'mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor'>
<class 'mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor'>
<class 'mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor'>
<class 'mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor'>
<class 'mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor'>
<class 'mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor'>
<class 'mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor'>
<class 'mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor'>
<class 'mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor'>
<class 'mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor'>
5.5.5-10.3.13-MariaDB-1:10.3.13+maria~bionic-log
5.5.5-10.3.13-MariaDB-1:10.3.13+maria~bionic-log
5.5.5-10.3.13-MariaDB-1:10.3.13+maria~bionic-log
<class 'mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor'>
<class 'mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor'>
<class 'mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor'>
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "for_stack.py", line 16, in DB
    cursor = connection_object.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 809, in cursor
    raise errors.OperationalError("MySQL Connection not available.")
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available.
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "for_stack.py", line 31, in <module>
    obj2.map(DB,massiv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 288, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 670, in get
    raise self._value
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available.
```

Строки `5.5.5-10.3.13-MariaDB-1:10.3.13+maria~bionic-log` и `<class 'mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor'>`  я написал для того,что бы убедиться,что внутри каждого дочернего процесса устанавливается соединение с базой данных,то есть берется соединение из пула (`connection_object = connection_pool.get_connection()`) и выполняется запрос к ней(к Базе Данных).

Проблема заключается в том,что запросы к базе данных действительно выполняются,при чем процессами с разными pid,что собственно и требуется, и некоторые данные заносятся,например после выполнения скрипта таблица в Базе Данных выглядит так:

```
+----+--------------+--------------+
| id | Variable     | Variable_2   |
+----+--------------+--------------+
|  1 | five         | five         |
|  2 | thirteen     | thirteen     |
|  3 | fourteen     | fourteen     |
|  4 | eleven       | eleven       |
|  5 | twelve       | twelve       |
|  6 | ten          | ten          |
|  7 | three        | three        |
|  8 | nine         | nine         |
|  9 | seven        | seven        |
| 10 | eight        | eight        |
| 11 | six          | six          |
| 12 | four         | four         |
| 13 | one          | one          |
| 14 | sixteen      | sixteen      |
| 15 | seventeen    | seventeen    |
| 16 | twenty one   | twenty one   |
| 17 | twenty three | twenty three |
| 18 | twenty two   | twenty two   |
+----+--------------+--------------+
```

, но собственно,вылезает ошибка,трейсбэк которой я скинул выше. Я не понимаю в чем может быть проблема. В multiprocessing, mysql.connector.pooling или что-то связано с областями памяти? Может,я просто упускаю какую-то очевидную деталь?

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Во-первых, у каждого процесса своя память, а значит не получится использовать общий `connection_pool`. Во-вторых, время запуска каждого отдельного процесса в тысячи раз больше, чем открытие соединения с базой. Похоже, что в не с той стороны к оптимизации подходите.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, если не получится использовать общий `connection_pool`,тогда почему запросы в базу данных выполняются  и в базу данных все же заносится информация? Я вычленил этот кусок кода,что бы было легче понять его логику и логику конкретно этой ошибки.На деле запросы в базу будут посылаться после выполнение трудоемкой операции,для которой требуется многопроцессорность. То есть запуск каждого отдельного процесса все же будет производиться и поэтому можно использовать мультипроцессорность во благо. А пул процессов это очень большой дополнительный плюс к производительности.

Comment: Либо у каждого процесса будет свой `connection_pool` либо его копия. В обоих случаях к базе вы через него обращаться сможете, только свою основную функцию пулинга он выполнять не будет. А во втором случае может ещё и глючить. С чем вы и столкнулись, возможно.